# Do hand-to-hand weapons count as one-handed or two-handed weapons?

Tags: dead-island-riptide

In Dead Island Riptide, there are but three classes of weapons that count as hand-to-hand weapons: brass knuckles, bronze knuckles, and claws.

John Morgan, the hand-to-hand specialist, has a skill called "One-handed weapon durability". You can guess what it does. Because of John Morgan's focus on hand-to-hand weapons, I'm curious if this skill applies to those weapons?

The hand-to-hand weapon is only shown on one hand, but he swings with both fists, and I don't believe that the weapon only applies half the time like that.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah I believe they are "one-handed" weapons even though he uses 2 hands.
John definitely gets a boost with all the Hand-to-Hand weapons regardless.